# spring mvc background image not working when url changes

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to give background. Image load properly when the url is (in login page)

```
/jobsspectrum/login
```

by using in profile page

```
<body background="resources/images/black.jpg">
```

But when the url changes the image does not load. eg.

```
/jobsspectrum/user/profile
because there is /user in the url before the page where i am using image in profile page.
```

the Error is

```
message /jobsspectrum/user/resources/images/black.jpg
description The requested resource is not available.
```

My image is under resources/images

It does not pick the resource when the url is not /jobsspectrum/

My resource handling class is :

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("resources/");
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
}
```

I simple words the image is picked only in the front pages and when the user logins my url changes from /jobsspectrum/ to /jobsspectrum/user/** and the resource image part is not loaded properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use absolute paths instead of relative ones.

With the JSTL:

```
<body background="<c:url value='/resources/images/black.jpg' />">
```

Or, without the JSTL:

```
<body background="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/black.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This helped and such a simple solution. Also you helped me a lot in my other questions. TY.. Both solution works.